# http json in IONIC view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Have list of project, fetched with succes from API service in my IONIC view. Now i need that when i click "see detail", the APP fetch details of project from API (or localstorage) and then render in the view.
This is my route:

```
.state('progetto', {
            url: "/progetto/:progettoId",
            controller: 'ProgettoCtrl',
            templateUrl: "shared/views/progetto.html"
        })
```

this is controller:

```
   "use strict";

var app = angular.module('ng-laravel');
app.controller('ProgettoCtrl',function($scope, $stateParams, $http, $rootScope,$ionicLoading,$cordovaDevice,$cordovaVibration,ionicToast,$ionicPlatform,$cordovaNetwork){
    var id_progetto = $stateParams.progettoId;
    $http.get('https://www.dreaminvest.it/dettagli-progetto?id=' + id_progetto).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.progetto = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // log error
    });
});

and this is the view:

    <ion-view title="Forget" hide-nav-bar="true" id="page1" class=" ">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="manual-ios-statusbar-padding" scroll="true" style="background: url(img/bg.jpg) center; background-size: cover;">

        <div class="hero no-header flat">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="app-icon"></div>
                <h2 class="light">Benvenuto</h2>
                <p class="stable">Dettagli del progetto</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row responsive-md">


         <div class="col col-25">
                    <h3 align="center" style="color:white">{{ progetto.titolo }}</h3>
                    <img ng-src="http://dreaminvest.it/banner/{{progetto.banner}}" width="100%" />
                    <div class="padding">
        <button type="submit" class="button button-full button-assertive ink">Vedi</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        <button ui-sref="login" class="button button-full button-clear button-light">back to login</button>

    </div>
</ion-content>
```

But not work...

Comment: What is the error that you are facing? any error in the console, did you check the response status from the server?

Comment: In console the API route is not fetched and the script doesen't generate any request... the same code, in another controller and view work as well...

Comment: Could you please upload your code in a plnkr or something so I can hep you out.

Answer (score 0):

Its a stupid issue. I have forgot to add reference to controller in index file